# Install rgl on R-Server Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, opengl, rgl

I want to to install rgl on R-Server, running on Ubuntu. 
At the bas prompt I installed

```
sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done The following extra packages will be installed:
>   libglu1-mesa The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   libglu1-mesa r-cran-rgl 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and
>   0 not upgraded. Need to get 1,645 kB of archives. After this
>   operation, 3,875 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want
>   to continue? [Y/n] Y Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   trusty/main libglu1-mesa amd64 9.0.0-2 [195 kB] Get:2
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe r-cran-rgl amd64
>   0.93.996-1 [1,450 kB] Fetched 1,645 kB in 1s (1,047 kB/s) Selecting previously unselected package libglu1-mesa:amd64. (Reading database
>   ... 55586 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to
>   unpack .../libglu1-mesa_9.0.0-2_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
>   libglu1-mesa:amd64 (9.0.0-2) ... Selecting previously unselected
>   package r-cran-rgl. Preparing to unpack
>   .../r-cran-rgl_0.93.996-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking r-cran-rgl
>   (0.93.996-1) ... Setting up libglu1-mesa:amd64 (9.0.0-2) ... Setting
>   up r-cran-rgl (0.93.996-1) ... Processing triggers for libc-bin
>   (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...

Thats it. The three points at the end do not indicate that there was more to copy. Then I logged in into R-Server and tried to run

```
install.packages("rgl", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

which resulted in an error, namely:

```
.... 
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking GL/glu.h usability... no
checking GL/glu.h presence... no
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/clambio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpT5iyrb/downloaded_packages’
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?!

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev` ? You might also need `libglu1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: @RHertel yep. On both I got errors like `E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]`. Then I read I can subsitute the from you suggested libraries with `sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl` but that did not do the trick neither.

Comment: The 404 error is strange. Could be a broken mirror. Maybe you can try with another site, like those listed in http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libglu1-mesa-dev/download and in http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/mesa-common-dev/download

Comment: @RHertel where would I add the mirror?

Comment: This would be in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The details are described in the frame on the top of the pages that I posted in my last comment. After adding such a line to `sources.list` you could try `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: Alternatively (and probably easier): Click on one of the links and choose to open the file in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by installing

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

then install in R again:

```
install.packages("rgl")
```